# In-place bitwise AND then restore original value

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a tight memory restriction where I am not allowed to allocate heap memory nor use local variables on stack for the following bit operation.

I have two integer values `A` and `B` (let's say they are just two byte values). I want to know what is the result of `A & B` (for example by `A &= B`) and then restore the original value of `A` into `A`.

As no extra memory is allowed, I can not temporarily store `A`'s original value. Can I simply use a sequence of bit operation to restore `A`'s value?

The reason for this is I have a big array of data where I need to count the bits after I bitwise-and something to it. But I need to retain the original value to test them against other values. The actual data is on a device where heap allocation is very expensive. And the data is dynamic in length so I can not declare a local variable to hold its temporary value.

Is this possible? If so how should I do it?

Comment: What do you need to use the result of `A & B` for?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `A & B`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Bitwise & is a destructive operation; you lose the original information.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Rather sounds like the OP is asking how to do `A & B`.

Comment: As @dbush said, just store the result in a cpu register creating a variable : `int C = A & B;` A won't change.

Comment: If you can't use local variables on the stack you have to write this in assembler. Because C may very well store unnamed local variables on the stack, rather than in registers - it is beyond your control.

Comment: you don't need to declare an array to store the original array. Just store the current element, `and` it then restore it

Comment: You don't need to allocate a copy of the whole array for this.  You should only need one local to store the result of the bitwise AND, and another to keep count of the number of bits set.

Comment: @dbush Thank you! I am being stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that you need to make a copy of the entire array, modify the copy, then perform operations on it.  That isn't necessary.

For each element of the array, calucate `A & B` and store it in a local.  Then count the number of bits set, and add that to a running total.

For example:

```
int count_bits_with_and(unsigned char *array, int size, unsigned char val)
{
    int i, sum;

    for (i=0, sum=0; i<size; i++) {
        unsigned char v = array[i] & val;
        int count = count_bits(v);
        sum += count;
    }
    return sum;
}
```